# Downloading a calendar item attachment using getAttachmentContentAsync returns different data between OWA and Outlook Desktop

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

When using getAttachmentContentAsync to retrieve the same [calendar item attachment](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/insert-calendar-event-email-attachment-outlook) to save from the same email, we're seeing a difference in behavior between Desktop Outlook clients and OWA.

When we attempt to open the saved calendar item, the calendar item downloaded from Outlook Desktop opens properly in Outlook or any native calendar application (Mac,Windows). However when opening the saved calendar item from OWA, both Outlook and native calendar applications are unable to open the event and display an error message along the lines of "*Your calendar file may be corrupted*".

***Is this expected behavior? Are add-ins running in OWA supposed to parse the AttachmentContent.content of .ics item attachments differently?***

**Steps to Reproduce**
1. View an email with a calendar item attachment in OWA or Outlook Desktop.
2. Download the calendar item attachment in an add-in context using [getAttachmentContentAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox.item#getattachmentcontentasyncattachmentid-options-callback--attachmentcontent).
3. Save the [AttachmentContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.attachmentcontent?view=outlook-js-1.8) that is returned. The format property should be iCalendar and should save as a .ics file.
4. Add the .ics calendar item to a native calendar application (Outlook Desktop, Mac Calendar, Windows Calendar)
5. Native calendar apps *are able to add* a .ics calendar item downloaded from Outlook Desktop works properly. Native calendar apps *are not able to add* a .ics calendar item downloaded from OWA.

**Code snippet (running in an add-in context)**

```
var attachmentIds = Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments.map(function (a) {
    return a.id;
})

Office.context.mailbox.item.getAttachmentContentAsync(attachmentIds[0], function (asyncResult) {
   // handle callback
   console.log(asyncResult.value.content); // attachmentContent
});
```

**Attachment Content**

*Observing the differences between the attachment content retrieved*

From Outlook Desktop (1911 12228.20332), the `AttachmentContent.content` of the calendar item attachment looks like

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 16.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Pacific Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16011104T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
TZOFFSETFROM:-0700
TZOFFSETTO:-0800
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010311T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
TZOFFSETFROM:-0800
TZOFFSETTO:-0700
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20191210T000228Z
DESCRIPTION:\n\n
DTEND;TZID="Pacific Standard Time":20170519T083000
DTSTAMP:20191210T003452Z
DTSTART;TZID="Pacific Standard Time":20170519T080000
LAST-MODIFIED:20191210T000228Z
PRIORITY:5
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;COUNT=12;BYMONTHDAY=19
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:Test Event
TRANSP:OPAQUE
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000A351638858C8D201000000000000000
    01000000041A54A4D53F4A1489A80440AC927AA24
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<html><head><style type="text/css" style="disp
    lay:none\;"><!-- P {margin-top:0\;margin-bottom:0\;} --></Style></Head><bo
    dy dir="ltr"><div id="divtagdefaultwrapper" style="font-size:12pt\;color:#
    000000\;font-family:Calibri\,Arial\,Helvetica\,sans-serif\;" dir="ltr"><p>
    <br>\n</P></Div></Body></Html>
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-APPTLASTSEQUENCE:0
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20191210T000228Z
DESCRIPTION:\n\n
DTEND:20170519T153000Z
DTSTAMP:20170509T001050Z
DTSTART:20170519T150000Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20191210T000228Z
PRIORITY:5
RECURRENCE-ID:20170519T150000Z
SEQUENCE:0
TRANSP:OPAQUE
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000A351638858C8D201000000000000000
    01000000041A54A4D53F4A1489A80440AC927AA24
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<html><head><style type="text/css" style="disp
    lay:none\;"><!-- P {margin-top:0\;margin-bottom:0\;} --></Style></Head><bo
    dy dir="ltr"><div id="divtagdefaultwrapper" style="font-size:12pt\;color:#
    000000\;font-family:Calibri\,Arial\,Helvetica\,sans-serif\;" dir="ltr"><p>
    <br>\n</P></Div></Body></Html>
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MS-OLK-APPTSEQTIME:20170509T001050Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

From OWA, the `AttachmentContent.content` looks like

```
From: Jules Wada <jules.wada@sfdcmsft.com>
Subject: Test Event
Thread-Index: AdLIWIhlDG6lIvpt90Gwy2I/zPumFg==
Date: Tue, 9 May 2017 00:09:31 +0000
Message-ID:
    <MWHPR08MB251172981867AF63CA5D3B59F3EF0@MWHPR08MB2511.namprd08.prod.outlook.com>
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-RecordReviewCfmType: 0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="_000_MWHPR08MB251172981867AF63CA5D3B59F3EF0MWHPR08MB2511namp_"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--_000_MWHPR08MB251172981867AF63CA5D3B59F3EF0MWHPR08MB2511namp_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

DQo=

--_000_MWHPR08MB251172981867AF63CA5D3B59F3EF0MWHPR08MB2511namp_
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

PGh0bWw+DQo8aGVhZD4NCjxtZXRhIGh0dHAtZXF1aXY9IkNvbnRlbnQtVHlwZSIgY29udGVudD0i
dGV4dC9odG1sOyBjaGFyc2V0PXV0Zi04Ij4NCjxzdHlsZSB0eXBlPSJ0ZXh0L2NzcyIgc3R5bGU9
ImRpc3BsYXk6bm9uZTsiPjwhLS0gUCB7bWFyZ2luLXRvcDowO21hcmdpbi1ib3R0b206MDt9IC0t
Pjwvc3R5bGU+DQo8L2hlYWQ+DQo8Ym9keSBkaXI9Imx0ciI+DQo8ZGl2IGlkPSJkaXZ0YWdkZWZh
dWx0d3JhcHBlciIgc3R5bGU9ImZvbnQtc2l6ZToxMnB0O2NvbG9yOiMwMDAwMDA7Zm9udC1mYW1p
bHk6Q2FsaWJyaSxBcmlhbCxIZWx2ZXRpY2Esc2Fucy1zZXJpZjsiIGRpcj0ibHRyIj4NCjxwPjxi
cj4NCjwvcD4NCjwvZGl2Pg0KPC9ib2R5Pg0KPC9odG1sPg0K

--_000_MWHPR08MB251172981867AF63CA5D3B59F3EF0MWHPR08MB2511namp_
Content-Type: text/calendar; charset="utf-8"; method=PUBLISH
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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--_000_MWHPR08MB251172981867AF63CA5D3B59F3EF0MWHPR08MB2511namp_--
```

Comment: Can you please provide exact steps to reproduce the problem ?
I could not understand whether you are saving event using add-in or outlook app.

Comment: Updated the post with some steps to reproduce. I'm downloading the content of an event that's attached to an email as a calendar item attachment(.ics).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the steps. Could you share us the code snippet as to what you're using to download the AttachmentContent? This might help us understand what's going wrong.

Comment: I'm using the getAttachmentContentAsync api call from office.js.

I'll update the post with the code snippet.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still unable to reproduce the issue that you're facing, so I will need a little more help from you. When you run the code snippet you shared, on both OWA and Outlook for Desktop, on an email item which has a calendar event attached (in .ics format), both of the `asyncResult.value.content` should give the exact same output, which is a Base64 encoded version of the attachment content. If you decode the content, you should get a formatted event just like you shared in the first instance. Is there anything different that you see `asyncResult.value.content` returning for you?

Comment: I also see the scenario mentioned above working when the Outlook item attachment is attached as a [file attachment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailboxenums.attachmenttype?view=outlook-js-preview). The scenario in the original post details when the Outlook item is attached as an item attachment MailboxEnums.AttachmentContentFormat != "base64". As per the documentation [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.attachmentcontent?view=outlook-js-preview#format) the value of asyncResult.value.content should represent an .iCal file.

Comment: The value of asyncResult.value.content is pasted in the original post verbatim between the 2 clients. AttachmentContent.format = "iCalendar" for the attachments and according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.attachmentcontent?view=outlook-js-preview#format), the content isn't base64 encoded.

Comment: For the contentFormat, we acknowledge there is a documentation bug and we will update that. For .ics and .eml the content format will be base64 only. 
The response of Outlook Desktop which you shared looks like the decoded version. Have you decoded the actual response of the API? The response of the API in both OWA and Desktop should be Base64 encoded and should be same.

Comment: In OWA, the response of the getAttachmentContentAsync api is { format: "iCalendar", content: <String posted above>}. It is not base64 encoded. In Outlook Desktop, the format is also "iCalendar", but the content is the string posted above for Desktop.

Would you like me to forward you an email with attachments that I can reproduce the issue with?

Comment: We are able to repro the issue. Thanks for reporting this issue. It has been put on our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point.

Comment: We do not see this issue on latest builds. Could you please check if you are still able to repro this issue?